# How to return the value of a column immediately after an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

One can read everything about the last_insert_id() out there. This makes me think that, in MySQL, there is no way to get other column values after an INSERT statement than the auto increment column of a table.

To be more clear:
If I have a table with column A (not necessarily a PK) that is generated by a trigger before insert, could I get the generated value after the INSERT ? Just like last_insert_id() would, just that I want to specify my custom column to return.

Thank you !

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Can you be little more specific.

Comment: Are you using a sequence?